# Оптимизация реализации программы

Tags: c#, многопоточность, кэширование

У меня будет программа, примерную реализацию я приведу в коде. Суть программы, вначале она получает данные из БД, затем эти данные приводит к какому-то виду ( проходит цикл по каждому значению данных), затем проходит 2 цикла. В первом цикле мы перебираем 2-8 параметров, которые служат входными данными в функцию, в котором есть свой цикл. В цикле мы по какому-то условию, добавляем элемент(объект) в массив в поле основного объекта и при определенном условии изменяем значение одного из свойств добавленного элемента в списке. Везде используется `List<double>` или `List<DateTime>`. Из-за того, что я в основном объекте использую массив, с которым работаю, при каждом проходе первого цикла я создаю новый основной объект. 
Простейший пример приведу в коде :

```
public class MainClass
{
    ListOfC array;
    List<double> x, y;
    // Здесь в основном я получаю данные из БД и через цикл добавляю их в x,y и создаю объект ListOfC; 

}

public class ListOfC
{
    List<C> arrayC;
    // Здесь пару функций добавления в массив arrayC;
}

public class C
{
    // Здесь имеются какие-то поля и пару функций для изменения этих полей
}

public class Realize
{
    public double Result()
    {
        // здесь я прохожу цикл из 1000 итераций, каждая из которых создает отдельный объект MainClass выполняет функцию Calc и получает результирующее значение, при каждом новом проходе мы имеем разные значения ListofC и поэтому создаем разные объекты MainClass
    }

    public double Calc()
    {
        // Здесь я прохожу цикл и в по условиям добавляю в ListOfC новые элементы и изменях их путем выбирания конкретного объекта в списке. 
    }
}
```

Из своих мыслей я думаю реализовать кэш, чтобы при каждом созданном объекте `MainClass` данные из БД в x и y каждый раз не брать. Ну и включить параллельное выполнение цикла из 1000 итераций т.к. каждая итерация не зависит от предыдущей. Кое как реализовал, скорость повысилась в разы, но не так быстро всё же, как в аналогичной программы, где 1000 итераций проходят за 1 секунду. Как можно достичь такого результата в 1 секунду? Я доходил до 10-18 секунд при просчете с `CacheMemory` и `AsParallel`.

Comment: Можно ли не скачивать данные из БД на комп, а переложить бОльшую часть вычислений на сервер БД? Пусть сам считает по-максимуму. В базе что-то есть, вы это что-то качаете и трансформируете -- а можно ведь и на сервере БД трансформировать, верно?

Comment: @AK на счет этого не думал, всё же я придерживаюсь больше к переносимости программы. Поэтому всё храню в файле SQLite. В аналогичной программе данные берутся просто из файла txt. Где парсируются и т п. Я думал, через файл БД быстрее будет.

Comment: Давать совет в вашей ситуации сложно: вы не рассказываете, какие операции делаете над данными; непонятен объём данных; решение лучше принимать после тщательного профилирования. Вы же движок делаете, тут неплохо бы сделать небольшое исследование и проработать оба варианта хотя бы вчерновую. У вас данные имеют фиксированную размерность, возможно тут достаточно редкий случай, когда можно обогнать БД на велосипеде.

Comment: Данные берутся 1 раз за 1000 итераций, дальше они лишь из кэша достаются.

Comment: @AK Операции над данными элементарные, я проверял скорость прохождения 1 итерации - 1 секунда. В 1 итерации вызывается функция расчета. В данной функции проходит цикл 5 тысяч и более. В данном цикле я вызываю функцию, которая добавляет `List<C>` новый объект и в нем инициализирует пару значений. Также, в конце цикла я возвращаю умножение суммы двух полей из всех значений List<C>. Всё, больше тут ничего не происходит.

Comment: Вы просите помочь оптимизировать код, который не показываете. Это не имеет смысла. Также, чтобы оптимизировать что то, надо понять. что именно тормозит - чтобы понять, что тормозит, надо профилировать, находить узкие места.

Comment: @tym32167 я вас понял. Просто, хотел получить общий ответ на данную тему, возможно, не использовать List<double>, а использовать double[] и т п.

Comment: @Fresto Я бы в первую очередь задумался над архитектурой и используемыми алгоритмами. Вы писали про перебор - так ли он нужен? Все ли значения надо перебирать? Можно ли смерджить циклы, что вы проходите? Надо ли вызывать все те функции, что вызываете? Есть ли более подходящий алгоритм/структура данных для хранения и обработки того, что храните и обрабатываете? Можно ли какие то данные предрасчитать, чтобы не пересчитывать каждый раз? Без предоставления кода никто не ответит на эти вопросы, кроме вас :)

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо, просто код большой и вставлять его сюда слишком сложно будет) Поэтому буду думать уже сам, как можно оптимизировать его, но спасибо за наводящие вопросы, буду на них опираться :)